# jQuery word cloud validation error

Tags: jquery, css, html, rel

Please Help!:)
I have problems when trying to validate(HTML5) jQuery word cloud.

I received this for all of the rel values:
"Bad value 1 for attribute rel on element a: Not an absolute IRI. The string 1 is not a registered keyword or absolute URL."

Also what amendments should I make in jQuery?![enter image description here][1]

```
  <div id="tagcloud">
    <a class="pointOne" rel="0.1" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
    <a class="two" rel="2" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
    <a class="three" rel="3" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
    <a class="four" rel="4" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
    <a class="five"rel="5" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="six" rel="6" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="seven" rel="7" href="http://www.text.dkk" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="eight" rel="8" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="five" rel="5" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="seven" rel="7" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text</a>
        <a class="three" rel="3" href="http://www.text.dk/" target="_blank">Text </a>
        <a class="one" rel="1" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="twelve"rel="12" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="one" rel="1" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="two" rel="2" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="five" rel="5" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="seven" rel="7" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="one" rel="1" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="four" rel="4" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="one" rel="1" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
        <a class="two" rel="2" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers [aren't valid values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/link) for the `rel` attribute:

> This attribute names a relationship of the linked document to the
>   current document. **The attribute must be a space-separated list of the
>   link types values**. The most common use of this attribute is to specify
>   a link to an external style sheet: the rel attribute is set to
>   stylesheet, and the href attribute is set to the URL of an external
>   style sheet to format the page.

Acceptable [link type values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Link_types) are: `alternate`, `archives`, `author`, `bookmark`, `external`, `first`, `help`, `icon`, `index`, `last`, `license`, `next`, `nofollow`, `noreferrer`, `pingback`, `prefetch`, `prev`, `search`, `stylesheet`, `sidebar`, `tag`, and `up`.

I suggest you use a [custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-%2a) instead, for example:

```
<a class="one" data-rel="1" href="http://www.text.dk/">Text</a>
```

Then modify your JavaScript accordingly to pick up the values from `data-rel` (or whatever you want to call it) instead of `rel`.